# Tool to programmatically draw logic circuits into PDF

Tags: windows, java, pdf, drawing

I'm looking for a (preferably open source) tool to visualize logic circuits such as this

### [image: circuit]

with the following constraints:

- The diagram description should be given programmatically (through java or by providing some kind of textual description which is read from a file; basically I want to be able to call a Java method - which, in turn, may run an external program; I do NOT want a visual tool which requires user input).
- The output should be a PDF.
- If possible, routing should be done automatically.
- It should run on **Windows**.

While this seems simple enough, I have not found anything satisfactory through extensive research. The tools that came closest were:

- the `tikz` package of Latex (running Latex is perfectly ok in my context, but for some reason the combination of Java and tikz broke down, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298548/pdflatex-run-crashes-when-executed-from-java-on-windows; also, as far as I know, tikz cannot auto-route).
- The `blockdiag` program (http://blockdiag.com/en/index.html) which is however, if I'm correct, not available for windows (and has no predefined logic gates).

I obviously looked at graphviz, but the problem there is that you cannot tell graphviz where exactly the edges should dock on to the nodes - which is essential if you want to specify inputs and outputs.

There is also this question on SE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422603/circuit-block-diagram-drawing.
But without going into detail, all of the suggestions there didn't work for me due to the above mentioned constraints.

I'd have expected this to be a problem solved many times before... (And maybe I just googled poorly.)

Comment: The Tikz approach should work fine. A solution for your hanging Java program is reasonably straightforward. Answer given in the linked question.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Thanks, I'm looking into it (I have tried redirecting the output before, though not in the same way; the suggestions seems reasonable after all; I'll let you know; with tikz I'll have to do the routing manually, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [SchemDraw](http://cdelker.bitbucket.org/SchemDraw/SchemDraw.html) which is a [python](http://python.org) package which:

- can output results in svg, eps, or pdf,
- allows you to define your own components,
- is cross platform, (including windows),
- is free, gratis & FOSS

You can either create the diagrams directly from python or you can define your own format for storing the information and parse it in.

Comment: This looks REALLY great! I've no experience with Python, but maybe this will be the ultimate reason to finally start learning it!

Answer (score 2):

There's a new project called [netlistsvg](https://github.com/nturley/netlistsvg) which may fit the bill; it's still in the early stages but is geared toward logic diagrams, and especially Verilog synthesis.